# Unknown CMake command "catkin_project"

Tags: catkin, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04
and Fuerte

I have downloaded the cyphy stack from ROS repositories.

Installed all the required dependencies

```
sai@sai:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosdep install cyphy_xsens_mtig
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

then when i did ROSMAKE

```
sai@sai:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosmake cyphy_xsens_mtig 



{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (catkin_project):
    Unknown CMake command "catkin_project".
  
  
  CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
    No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as
  
      cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
  
    should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
    if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
    information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
  This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

This is the error..

Please let me know how this issue can be solved.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42325/unknown-cmake-command-%22catkin_project%22/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-26**:
I resolved the issue by changing the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable. i gave the priority to the packages downloaded during installation than the packages downloaded from repository. Finally it worked..I mean i was able to ROSMAKE but when i do ROSRUN..I m not getting the output..Unable to connect to Mti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the project you are trying to compile already use the new ROS build system catkin. You cannot build that with rosmake. You can find some documentation [here](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3